# MVC3 How to pass data to contoller from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Passing data from a controller to another controller. this is what i am doing, but I dont think it is the correct way of doing it, plz help me modify the code for it to work, share example/tutorial..

e.g

> I am using Membership API to create a user account

```
public ActionResult Register() { return View(); }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model)
{
  //creates an account and redirect to CompanyController
  //Also I want to store the userId and pass it to the next controller, I am using a session, ok? 
  Session["userObject"] = userIdGenerated()
  return RedirectToAction("Create", "Company");          
}
```

> CompanyController:

```
public ActionResult Create() { return View(); }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CompanyInformation companyinformation)
{
   //creating company account and I need to store the userid to the company table retrieving from a session
   companyinformation.UserID = Session["userObject"].ToString();
   db.CompanyInformation.Add(companyinformation);
   db.SaveChanges();

   //retrieving companyId that was generated and need to pass to the next controller I tried to use "TempData["companyId"] = companyinformation.CompanyInformationID" But the data is no longer found on httpPost

return RedirectToAction("Create", "Contact");
```

}

> Contact controller

```
  public ActionResult Create()
  {
   //I tried using ViewBag to store the data from TempDate but the data is no longer found on httpPost
        ViewBag.companyId = TempData["companyId"].ToString();
        return View();
   }

 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create(CompanyContact companycontact)
 {
     companycontact.CompanyInformationID = ???? How do I get the companyId?
     db.CompanyContacts.Add(companycontact);
     db.SaveChanges();
    //Redirect to the next controller...
 }
```

I hope it is clear what I am trying to do. Maybe use ViewModels but I am not sure how to put it together... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your `UserID` parameter directly to your controller's method as it was a *standard* navigation flow

`RedirectToAction` has one [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460311.aspx) that allows you to set `routeValues`.

```
  return RedirectToAction("Create", "Company", new { id = userIdGenerated() });
```

And in your `CompanyController`

```
public ActionResult Create(int id) { return View(id); }
```

Since you will have your `id` in the URL, then you would be able to catch it in your post as well:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int id, CompanyInformation companyinformation)
```

Or you can persist it into the model `CompanyInformation` on GET `Create`

Comment: Hi Stéphane, thanks! appreciate your help, can you plz example me by what you mean "Or you can persist it into the model CompanyInformation on GET Create", Is this ModelView? could you provide me an example...

Comment: I mean if your `CompanyInformation` has a UserId property then you can do something like this in your create action `return View(new CompanyInformation { UserId = id});` and persists it into the view in an hidden field for instance `@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UserId)`

Comment: sorry for asking so much, last question, the first example you 
should was by passing the data via URL, and if I wanted to pass the data without showing the data in the URL, is it possible? how would you do it? Thanks again!

Comment: So `TempData` is your friend as the previous answer said. See this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394711.aspx): Passing State Between Action Methods.

Comment: I thought TempData is not good for this scenario because I use Httppost and the data is not there if I try to retrieve it...

Comment: TempData are persisted in the session state until the session expires or you retrieve tem.

Answer (score 2):

```
public ActionResult Action1()
{
   TempData["key"]  =Some_Object;
  return RedirectToAction("Action2");
}

public ActionResult Action2()
{
     var data= TempData["key"];
}
```

Use `TempData`

https://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+mvc+tempdata&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 1):

You can use TempData for it.

Please find more details in below link
http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications

Comment: Here is a scenario, lets say user goes to Controller1 it creates a TempData (userId) and then redirects to Controller2 it uses the value and then the user decides to go back to Controlle1 and to Controller2 but the value is no longer available... how would you handle it? How would I keep a value across the controllers?  thx

Comment: Assign your userid again in TempData on controller2 so that you will easily get that value on controller1.